# Question about the use of "that's" and the portmanteau word "tigon"

Tags: spelling, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

I think I've found two errors in [this passage](http://wonderopolis.org/wonder/are-ligers-real/) (marked as bold):

> Ligers tend to have characteristics more like lions than tigers. A creature can be created **that’s** more like a tiger, though. This offspring of a male tiger and a female lion is called a **tigon**.

QUESTIONS:

1. I think that the phrase "that's" is superfluous and the text would be better if it was deleted.  Am I right? (But if that phrase "that's" is acceptable, then what function is it performing here?)
2. I think that the name of that animal was misspelled and it should have been spelled as "tiglon". Am I right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by '"that's" is superfluous'? I suppose you could do without it, but for me it sits comfortably in the sentence and adds clarity. As for the spelling of the animal I'm not sure. Is it a real word?

Comment: Thanks for the kind edition by F.E.. As an English learner I must admit I still don't know why there is "that's" there.What does "that" refer to?  I can understand either "that’s more like a tiger." or "A creature can be created",but to join the two in one sentence? Maybe I need more similar example sentences to make myself clear.

Comment: Compare your original sentence to something like: *"A creature [that’s more like a tiger] can be created"*. A difference is that. in the original, the relative clause seems to have been raised out of the NP and moved to the end of the main clause. This sometimes happens when the original subject would be very heavy, and so, the relative clause is moved out in order to lighten the subject's weight--this makes the sentence easier to parse and understand. But be aware there are severe restrictions as to when this kind of movement can be done.

Comment: Can I make a sentence like "A house can be decorated that's like a palace."? I would rather say "A house can be decorated like a palace.".

Comment: The original version with "that's" seems to be better than the version without it, for the given context.

Comment: @F.E. Your explanation is fantastic! Now I think I've got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: With your last example (in your comments), there's some differences between that and the example in the OP. One is that the last example won't have the same meaning if the clause was stuck inside the subject NP: compare to *"A house [ (that's) like a palace] can be decorated".*

Comment: *'The original version with "that's" seems to be better than the version without it, for the given context.'* <== When I said this earlier in the comments, I was referring to the original example in the OP ("Original Post").

Comment: @F.E. I see. As you said, "there are severe restrictions as to when this kind of movement can be done", to make the sentence more balanced.

Answer (score 3):

You are rather too quick to say that the name of the animal 'should' be spelled 'tiglon' (I assume that you've encountered that spelling before). Maulik has provided one reference to show that 'tigon' and 'tiglon' are both used, and [Google N-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tigon%2Ctiglon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctigon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctiglon%3B%2Cc0) shows that both words are used with about equal frequency.

'that ...' is a defining relative clause - it tells us exactly which creature can be created. 'that' used in this way can be omitted in certain circumstances, this being one of them. I would retain 'that' for clarity.

By the way, the offspring of a female tiger and a male lion is a liger.

Answer (score 2):

If I were rewriting that sentence

> A creature can be created that's more like a tiger.

and had been instructed to avoid using a clause that explicitly begins the word "that", it would go as follows:

> A creature can be created *to be* more like a tiger.
>
> A creature more like a tiger can be created.

That is, I'd want to add "to be" (so as to be), or I'd want to move the "more like a tiger" ahead of the verb-phrase.